# React ambiguous error messaging: "Check the render method of `Constructor`."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm using React on the client side to render my application's views.

When I view error reporting in my browser console I sometimes see errors with
`Check the render method of 'Constructor'` instead of the proper name of the class where the error is occurring.

**e.g.,** I'll see a message like:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `Constructor`. See https://<fb.me>/react-warning-keys for more information.
```

Why is my class's name appearing as `Constructor`? How do I get React to properly display the class's name.

---

Other details:

- Currently I create classes using `React.createClass()` (i.e., *not* the ES6 way)
- Some of my classes are created using `React.createBackboneClass()` from https://github.com/clayallsopp/react.backbone to facilitate the interaction of React with our legacy Backbone models / collections
- Using `gulp` and `babel` to compile my JSX files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happened because your components created with `createClass` don't have proper `displayName`. Write display name to each component in your application, and you will see normal message.

UPD:

For example:

```
const SomeComponent = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'SomeComponent',
    ...
    render() {
        ...
    }
});

export default SomeComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#displayname):

> displayName
>   `string displayName`

The `displayName` string is used in debugging messages. JSX sets this value automatically;

Try this:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({

  displayName: 'Hello World', // here

  render: function() {
    console.log(this.displayName);
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});
```